# Why is Rails not auto-generating .created_at?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

I have a scaffold-generated model called 'Pac' (political action committee), which has timestamps.

I am trying to seed data about pacs from a text file. In my seeds.rb file, I parse the text file to obtain a hash of data, corresponding to the attributes of my ActiveRecord::Pac class. This hash is called 'pac_attributes'.

Now I try

```
Pac.find_or_create_by(pac_attributes)
```

and I get the following error:

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: pacs.created_at
```

Well, ActiveRecord::Pac has timestamps, and and my 'pac_attributes' hash does not have explicit entries for 'created_at' and 'updated_at', but every time I've ever used find_or_create_by in the past these fields are genreated automatically (as is the 'id' field).

What is happening? Why is 'find_or_create_by' failing and throwing this error?

At the request of commentors, I have added the following information:

Excerpt from schema.rb file:

```
create_table "pacs", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "cycle"
  t.string "fec_id"
  t.string "pacshort"
  t.string "affiliate"
  t.string "ultorg"
  t.string "recipient_id"
  t.string "recipient_code"
  t.string "fec_candidate_id"
  t.string "party"
  t.string "prim_code"
  t.string "source"
  t.string "sensitive"
  t.boolean "foreign"
  t.integer "active"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

To get the 'pac_attributes' hash I do the following:

```
pac_columns = Pac.column_names
pac_columns.delete_if { |x| x=='id' or x=='created_at' or x=='updated_at' }
puts pac_columns
pacs = File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'assets', 'tables', 'cmtes18.txt' )
IO.foreach(pacs) do |line|
  line.chomp!("\r\n")
  pac_data = line.split(',')
  pac_data.each do |data|
    data.gsub!(/\|/,"")
    #The textfile is formatted with entries comma-separated and enclosed in '|' characters

  end
  pac_attributes = pac_columns.map(&:to_sym).zip(pac_data).to_h
  pac_attributes.delete_if{|_,v| v=="" }
  puts pac_attributes
  pac = Pac.find_or_create_by(pac_attributes)
end
```

'puts pac_attributes' returns:

```
{:cycle=>"2018", :fec_id=>"C00000018", :recipient_id=>"C00000018", :fec_candidate_id=>"H8TX22313", :foreign=>"0", :active=>"0"}
```

The development logs return the following:

```
[1m[36mPac Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "pacs".* FROM "pacs" WHERE "pacs"."cycle" = ? AND "pacs"."fec_id" = ? AND "pacs"."recipient_id" = ? AND "pacs"."fec_candidate_id" = ? AND "pacs"."foreign" = ? AND "pacs"."active" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["cycle", "2018"], ["fec_id", "C00000018"], ["recipient_id", "C00000018"], ["fec_candidate_id", "H8TX22313"], ["foreign", "0"], ["active", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[36mbegin transaction[0m
[1m[35mSQL (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[32mINSERT INTO "pacs" ("cycle", "fec_id", "recipient_id", "fec_candidate_id", "foreign", "active") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["cycle", "2018"], ["fec_id", "C00000018"], ["recipient_id", "C00000018"], ["fec_candidate_id", "H8TX22313"], ["foreign", "f"], ["active", 0]]
[1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[31mrollback transaction[0m
```

Comment: Sounds like you left `t.timestamps` out of your migration file.

Comment: It's in my migration file.

Comment: Maybe an excerpt of the table from the `schema.rb` or `structure.sql`  might help...

Comment: @ma_il I added the table excerpt from schema.rb to the original post.

Comment: What does `pac_attributes` look like? Does it perchance contain the `created_at` key without a value?

Comment: In short, no, <pac_attributes> does not contain a 'created_at' key. <pac_attributes> is a hash created by zipping together two arrays. The keys are taken from <Pac.column_names> with 'id', 'created_at', and 'updated_at' subsequently deleted. The values are parsed from a line in a text-file. After zipping the two arrays into a hash, I delete all (key,value) pairs with an empty-string value.

Comment: What SQL statements does the log show? And, just to be thorough, did you restart the application and any spring preloader or so that you might be running? I assume so, but [the implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/18f83faf711a4a89b0eef482c775129751d91644/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L153) of `find_or_create_by` is so straightforward that I don't really understand how this can be the case. It just calls [create](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3b2ea8b68352c1c4534ff30a086a16d00e8a12cf/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L31) after all...

Comment: @LelandReardon can you post the code you're using to delete the key value pairs? Any chance you're returning something you didn't expect (e.g. map vs another method)

Comment: please add the content of pac_attributes

Comment: I've added the method by which I create the array of column names, as well as the output of pac_attributes.

Comment: Unless you show your "work" in the console, it's hard to follow and hard to debug. Without seeing EXACTLY what you're doing and the values printed out by the console, it's hard to know if your assumptions are true, or are the root of the bug.

Comment: Okay gang, I've added logs from 'development.log' and added the whole script I'm using to build the 'pac_attributes' hash. Thanks for bearing with me and let me know if you want to see anything else.